# Getting None even after selecting option in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

What I want to do is get the option that the user selects from my **Html** select form and then work with it. I've tried accessing those values like `print(request.POST.get('variations', None))` and even after selecting option, it's returning `None`. I am not really understanding why. Can anyone please help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

My html form:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{{ object.get_add_to_cart_url }}">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {% for var in object.variation_set.all %}
      <h5>Choose {{ var.name }}</h5>
        <select class="form-control mb-4 col-md-4" title="variations">
          {% for item in var.itemvariation_set.all %}
            <option value="{{ item.value }}">{{ item.value|capfirst }}</option>
          {% endfor %}  
        </select>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="action">
      <button class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>
     <button class="like btn btn-danger" type="button"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

> I want to get what the user has selected and work with them in this view, i.e while adding a product to the cart.

My views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)

    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user= request.user,
        ordered=False,
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            print(request.POST.get('variations', None)) 
            messages.success(request, "Product quantity has been updated.")
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            print(request.POST.get('variations', None)) 
            messages.success(request, "Product added to cart.")
            return redirect("order-summary")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        print(request.POST.get('variations', None)) 
        messages.success(request, "Product added to cart.")
        return redirect("order-summary")
    return redirect("order-summary")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `<select>`'s "title" attribute to be called "name".

```
<select class="form-control mb-4 col-md-4" title="variations">
```

to

```
<select class="form-control mb-4 col-md-4" name="variations">
```